# Why don't I get a module dependencies?

Tags: commerce

I've got very little knowledge but I've managed to install Drupal Commerce 2 on a Debian 9 with the command

`composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base mysite --stability dev`

I started off with a minimal debian installation so I really had to look around to resolve any dependencies just to get this composer command to work! It's not as straight-forward as the manual seems to suggest. Anyways, I've got a site installed now and besides a few suggestions from composer, I don't think I have received any errors.
I can browse to the installed site with my web browser but I'm stuck on page 2 (Verify requirements) where it says

> **REQUIRED MODULES: Not found Commerce_log, Commerce_tax**

Where do I get the modules from and how? Isn't composer supposed to resolve all dependencies and have these modules installed automatically?

Besides the error that stops me from continuing the creation of the site, I get a warning on CLEAN URLS (disabled).

Here is the log of my composer installation:

```
composer create-project drupalcommerce/project-base mystore --stability dev --verbose
Installing drupalcommerce/project-base (8.x-dev 44c1fe21fbd9155a294c4b8fe0eaac0195a0f585)
  - Installing drupalcommerce/project-base (8.x-dev 44c1fe2): Cloning 44c1fe21fbd9155a294c4b8fe0eaac0195a0f585 from cache
Created project in mystore
> pre-update-cmd: DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
Loading composer repositories with packagUpdating dependencies (including require-dev)         Dependency resolution completed in 9.290 seconds
Analyzed 11720 packages to resolve dependencies
Analyzed 485242 rules to resolve dependencies
Dependency resolution completed in 0.000 seconds
Package operations: 122 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
Installs: cweagans/composer-patches:1.6.1, drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold:2.3.0, composer/installers:v1.4.0, symfony/yaml:v2.8.26, symfony/finder:v3.3.6, drupal/console-extend-plugin:0.9.2, drupalcommerce/commerce_base:dev-8.x-1.x 241bcf3, zendframework/zend-stdlib:3.1.0, zendframework/zend-escaper:2.5.2, zendframework/zend-feed:2.8.0, psr/http-message:1.0.1, zendframework/zend-diactoros:1.4.0, twig/twig:v1.34.4, symfony/polyfill-mbstring:v1.4.0, symfony/translation:v2.8.26, ircmaxell/password-compat:v1.0.4, symfony/polyfill-php55:v1.4.0, symfony/polyfill-php54:v1.4.0, symfony/http-foundation:v2.8.26, symfony/psr-http-message-bridge:v1.0.0, symfony/polyfill-iconv:v1.4.0, symfony/event-dispatcher:v2.8.26, psr/log:1.0.2, symfony/debug:v2.8.26, symfony/http-kernel:v2.8.26, symfony/routing:v2.8.26, symfony-cmf/routing:1.4.1, stack/builder:v1.0.4, paragonie/random_compat:v2.0.10, masterminds/html5:2.2.2, guzzlehttp/psr7:1.4.2, guzzlehttp/promises:v1.3.1, guzzlehttp/guzzle:6.3.0, doctrine/lexer:v1.0.1, egulias/email-validator:1.2.14, easyrdf/easyrdf:0.9.1, doctrine/inflector:v1.2.0, doctrine/collections:v1.4.0, doctrine/cache:v1.6.2, doctrine/annotations:v1.2.7, doctrine/common:v2.7.3, composer/semver:1.4.2, asm89/stack-cors:1.1.0, symfony/validator:v2.8.26, symfony/serializer:v2.8.26, symfony/process:v2.8.26, symfony/dependency-injection:v2.8.26, symfony/console:v2.8.26, symfony/polyfill-apcu:v1.4.0, symfony/class-loader:v2.8.26, drupal/core:8.3.6, drupal/admin_toolbar:1.19.0, psr/simple-cache:1.0.0, psr/cache:1.0.1, symfony/cache:v3.3.6, symfony/expression-language:v3.3.6, symfony/dom-crawler:v3.3.6, symfony/css-selector:v2.8.26, jakub-onderka/php-console-color:0.1, jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter:v0.3.2, dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir:0.1, nikic/php-parser:v3.1.0, symfony/var-dumper:v3.3.6, psy/psysh:v0.8.11, gabordemooij/redbean:v4.3.4, vlucas/phpdotenv:v2.4.0, drupal/console-dotenv:0.3.0, webmozart/assert:1.2.0, webmozart/path-util:2.3.0, webflo/drupal-finder:0.3.0, symfony/filesystem:v3.3.6, symfony/config:v3.2.13, stecman/symfony-console-completion:0.7.0, drupal/console-en:1.0.0, dflydev/placeholder-resolver:v1.0.2, dflydev/dot-access-data:v1.1.0, dflydev/dot-access-configuration:v1.0.2, drupal/console-core:1.0.0, alchemy/zippy:0.4.3, drupal/console:1.0.0, commerceguys/intl:v0.7.4, drupal/state_machine:1.0.0-beta3, drupal/entity:dev-1.x 6bf9d50, drupal/profile:dev-1.x 75637f8, drupal/entity_reference_revisions:1.3.0, drupal/inline_entity_form:1.0.0-beta1, commerceguys/enum:v1.0, commerceguys/addressing:v1.0.0-beta3, drupal/address:1.1.0, drupal/commerce:2.0.0-beta3, drupal/search_api:1.3.0, html2text/html2text:4.0.1, swiftmailer/swiftmailer:v5.4.8, drupal/mailsystem:4.1.0, drupal/swiftmailer:1.0.0-beta1, symfony/browser-kit:v3.3.6, fabpot/goutte:v3.2.1, behat/mink:v1.7.1, behat/mink-browserkit-driver:v1.3.2, behat/mink-goutte-driver:v1.2.1, jcalderonzumba/gastonjs:v1.0.3, jcalderonzumba/mink-phantomjs-driver:v0.3.3, mikey179/vfsStream:v1.6.5, sebastian/version:1.0.6, sebastian/global-state:1.1.1, sebastian/recursion-context:1.0.5, sebastian/exporter:1.2.2, sebastian/environment:1.3.8, sebastian/diff:1.4.3, sebastian/comparator:1.2.4, doctrine/instantiator:1.0.5, phpunit/php-text-template:1.2.1, phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects:2.3.8, phpunit/php-timer:1.0.9, phpunit/php-file-iterator:1.4.2, phpunit/php-token-stream:1.4.11, phpunit/php-code-coverage:2.2.4, phpdocumentor/reflection-common:1.0, phpdocumentor/type-resolver:0.3.0, phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock:3.2.2, phpspec/prophecy:v1.7.0, phpunit/phpunit:4.8.36
  - Installing cweagans/composer-patches (1.6.1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for cweagans/composer-patches.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold (2.3.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing composer/installers (v1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for composer/installers.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/yaml (v2.8.26): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/yaml.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/finder (v3.3.6): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/finder.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/console-extend-plugin (0.9.2): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for drupal/console-extend-plugin.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupalcommerce/commerce_base (dev-8.x-1.x 241bcf3): Cloning 241bcf336c92abaac8275807ce552bea846bbee0 from cache
No patches found for drupalcommerce/commerce_base.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing zendframework/zend-stdlib (3.1.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for zendframework/zend-stdlib.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing zendframework/zend-escaper (2.5.2): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for zendframework/zend-escaper.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing zendframework/zend-feed (2.8.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for zendframework/zend-feed.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing psr/http-message (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for psr/http-message.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing zendframework/zend-diactoros (1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for zendframework/zend-diactoros.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing twig/twig (v1.34.4): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for twig/twig.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/polyfill-mbstring.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/translation (v2.8.26): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/translation.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing ircmaxell/password-compat (v1.0.4): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for ircmaxell/password-compat.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php55 (v1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/polyfill-php55.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-php54 (v1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/polyfill-php54.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v2.8.26): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/http-foundation.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/psr-http-message-bridge (v1.0.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/psr-http-message-bridge.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-iconv (v1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/polyfill-iconv.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.8.26): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/event-dispatcher.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for psr/log.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/debug (v2.8.26): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/debug.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v2.8.26): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/http-kernel.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/routing (v2.8.26): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/routing.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony-cmf/routing (1.4.1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony-cmf/routing.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing stack/builder (v1.0.4): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for stack/builder.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v2.0.10): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for paragonie/random_compat.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing masterminds/html5 (2.2.2): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for masterminds/html5.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.4.2): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for guzzlehttp/psr7.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing guzzlehttp/promises (v1.3.1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for guzzlehttp/promises.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (6.3.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for guzzlehttp/guzzle.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for doctrine/lexer.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing egulias/email-validator (1.2.14): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for egulias/email-validator.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing easyrdf/easyrdf (0.9.1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for easyrdf/easyrdf.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.2.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for doctrine/inflector.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing doctrine/collections (v1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for doctrine/collections.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing doctrine/cache (v1.6.2): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for doctrine/cache.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.2.7): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for doctrine/annotations.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing doctrine/common (v2.7.3): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for doctrine/common.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing composer/semver (1.4.2): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for composer/semver.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing asm89/stack-cors (1.1.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for asm89/stack-cors.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/validator (v2.8.26): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/validator.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/serializer (v2.8.26): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/serializer.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/process (v2.8.26): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/process.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/dependency-injection (v2.8.26): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/dependency-injection.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/console (v2.8.26): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/console.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-apcu (v1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/polyfill-apcu.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/class-loader (v2.8.26): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/class-loader.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/core (8.3.6): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for drupal/core.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/admin_toolbar (1.19.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for drupal/admin_toolbar.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for psr/simple-cache.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing psr/cache (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for psr/cache.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/cache (v3.3.6): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/cache.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/expression-language (v3.3.6): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/expression-language.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/dom-crawler (v3.3.6): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/dom-crawler.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/css-selector (v2.8.26): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/css-selector.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-color (0.1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for jakub-onderka/php-console-color.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter (v0.3.2): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for jakub-onderka/php-console-highlighter.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir (0.1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for dnoegel/php-xdg-base-dir.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing nikic/php-parser (v3.1.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for nikic/php-parser.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v3.3.6): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/var-dumper.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing psy/psysh (v0.8.11): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for psy/psysh.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing gabordemooij/redbean (v4.3.4): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for gabordemooij/redbean.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing vlucas/phpdotenv (v2.4.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for vlucas/phpdotenv.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/console-dotenv (0.3.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for drupal/console-dotenv.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing webmozart/assert (1.2.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for webmozart/assert.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing webmozart/path-util (2.3.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for webmozart/path-util.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing webflo/drupal-finder (0.3.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for webflo/drupal-finder.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/filesystem (v3.3.6): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/filesystem.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/config (v3.2.13): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/config.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing stecman/symfony-console-completion (0.7.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for stecman/symfony-console-completion.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/console-en (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for drupal/console-en.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing dflydev/placeholder-resolver (v1.0.2): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for dflydev/placeholder-resolver.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing dflydev/dot-access-data (v1.1.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for dflydev/dot-access-data.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing dflydev/dot-access-configuration (v1.0.2): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for dflydev/dot-access-configuration.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/console-core (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for drupal/console-core.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing alchemy/zippy (0.4.3): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for alchemy/zippy.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/console (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for drupal/console.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing commerceguys/intl (v0.7.4): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for commerceguys/intl.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/state_machine (1.0.0-beta3): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for drupal/state_machine.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/entity (dev-1.x 6bf9d50): Cloning 6bf9d5039a2fa4a9cd596d0a3d6b41b5d70f04cb from cache
No patches found for drupal/entity.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/profile (dev-1.x 75637f8): Cloning 75637f87825aed9bb0cad0d912ee3bbe88383610 from cache
No patches found for drupal/profile.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/entity_reference_revisions (1.3.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for drupal/entity_reference_revisions.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/inline_entity_form (1.0.0-beta1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for drupal/inline_entity_form.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing commerceguys/enum (v1.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for commerceguys/enum.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing commerceguys/addressing (v1.0.0-beta3): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for commerceguys/addressing.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/address (1.1.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for drupal/address.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/commerce (2.0.0-beta3): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for drupal/commerce.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/search_api (1.3.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for drupal/search_api.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing html2text/html2text (4.0.1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for html2text/html2text.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.8): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for swiftmailer/swiftmailer.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/mailsystem (4.1.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for drupal/mailsystem.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing drupal/swiftmailer (1.0.0-beta1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for drupal/swiftmailer.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing symfony/browser-kit (v3.3.6): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for symfony/browser-kit.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing fabpot/goutte (v3.2.1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for fabpot/goutte.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing behat/mink (v1.7.1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for behat/mink.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing behat/mink-browserkit-driver (v1.3.2): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for behat/mink-browserkit-driver.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing behat/mink-goutte-driver (v1.2.1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for behat/mink-goutte-driver.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing jcalderonzumba/gastonjs (v1.0.3): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for jcalderonzumba/gastonjs.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing jcalderonzumba/mink-phantomjs-driver (v0.3.3): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for jcalderonzumba/mink-phantomjs-driver.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing mikey179/vfsstream (v1.6.5): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for mikey179/vfsstream.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing sebastian/version (1.0.6): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for sebastian/version.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing sebastian/global-state (1.1.1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for sebastian/global-state.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing sebastian/recursion-context (1.0.5): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for sebastian/recursion-context.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing sebastian/exporter (1.2.2): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for sebastian/exporter.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing sebastian/environment (1.3.8): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for sebastian/environment.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing sebastian/diff (1.4.3): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for sebastian/diff.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing sebastian/comparator (1.2.4): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for sebastian/comparator.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.5): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for doctrine/instantiator.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing phpunit/php-text-template (1.2.1): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for phpunit/php-text-template.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects (2.3.8): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing phpunit/php-timer (1.0.9): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for phpunit/php-timer.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing phpunit/php-file-iterator (1.4.2): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for phpunit/php-file-iterator.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing phpunit/php-token-stream (1.4.11): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for phpunit/php-token-stream.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing phpunit/php-code-coverage (2.2.4): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for phpunit/php-code-coverage.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-common (1.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for phpdocumentor/reflection-common.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing phpdocumentor/type-resolver (0.3.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for phpdocumentor/type-resolver.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (3.2.2): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing phpspec/prophecy (v1.7.0): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for phpspec/prophecy.
Patching is disabled. Skipping.
  - Installing phpunit/phpunit (4.8.36): Downloading (100%)
 Extracting archiveNo patches found for phpunit/phpunit.
zendframework/zend-feed suggests installing zendframework/zend-cache (Zend\Cache component, for optionally caching feeds between requests)
zendframework/zend-feed suggests installing zendframework/zend-db (Zend\Db component, for use with PubSubHubbub)
zendframework/zend-feed suggests installing zendframework/zend-http (Zend\Http for PubSubHubbub, and optionally for use with Zend\Feed\Reader)
zendframework/zend-feed suggests installing zendframework/zend-servicemanager (Zend\ServiceManager component, for easily extending ExtensionManager implementations)
zendframework/zend-feed suggests installing zendframework/zend-validator (Zend\Validator component, for validating email addresses used in Atom feeds and entries ehen using the Writer subcomponent)
paragonie/random_compat suggests installing ext-libsodium (Provides a modern crypto API that can be used to generate random bytes.)
easyrdf/easyrdf suggests installing ml/json-ld (~1.0)
symfony/validator suggests installing symfony/intl ()
symfony/validator suggests installing symfony/property-access (For using the 2.4 Validator API)
symfony/serializer suggests installing symfony/property-access (For using the ObjectNormalizer.)
symfony/dependency-injection suggests installing symfony/proxy-manager-bridge (Generate service proxies to lazy load them)
symfony/var-dumper suggests installing ext-symfony_debug ()
psy/psysh suggests installing ext-pdo-sqlite (The doc command requires SQLite to work.)
psy/psysh suggests installing hoa/console (A pure PHP readline implementation. You'll want this if your PHP install doesn't already support readline or libedit.)
alchemy/zippy suggests installing guzzle/guzzle (To use the GuzzleTeleporter with Guzzle 3)
commerceguys/addressing suggests installing symfony/intl (to use it as the source of country data)
behat/mink suggests installing behat/mink-selenium2-driver (slow, but JS-enabled driver for any app (requires Selenium2))
behat/mink suggests installing behat/mink-zombie-driver (fast and JS-enabled headless driver for any app (requires node.js))
sebastian/global-state suggests installing ext-uopz (*)
phpunit/php-code-coverage suggests installing ext-xdebug (>=2.2.1)
phpunit/phpunit suggests installing phpunit/php-invoker (~1.1)
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Downloading (100%)Downloading (100%)Downloading (100%)Downloading (100%)Downloading (100%)Downloading (100%)Downloading (100%)Downloading (100%)Downloading (100%)Downloading (100%)Downloading (100%)Downloading (100%)Downloading (100%)Downloading (100%)Downloading (100%)Creating packages services cache file:
/var/www/drupal/mystore/vendor/drupal/console/extend.console.uninstall.services.yml
> post-update-cmd: DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles
Create a sites/default/settings.php file with chmod 0666
Create a sites/default/services.yml file with chmod 0666
Create a sites/default/files directory with chmod 0777
Do you want to remove the existing VCS (.git, .svn..) history? [Y,n]? y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this issue, using the same installation method.

I tried manually requiring the newer version with:

```
composer require "drupal/commerce 2.x-dev"
```

Which gave me an error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
Problem 1
- Installation request for drupal/commerce 2.x-dev -> satisfiable by drupal/commerce[2.x-dev].
- drupal/commerce 2.x-dev requires ext-bcmath * -> the requested PHP extension bcmath is missing from your system.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- /etc/php/cli-php7.0/php.ini
- /etc/php/cli-php7.0/ext-active/opcache.ini
You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

**Solution**:
Updating PHP to use **bcmath** and restarting the web server solved the problem for me.  Installation is now progressing normally.

Comment: Dude, you da man! :D

Comment: Wow, that's crazy. Jakke didn't have bcmath, so Composer selected the last release without the bcmath requirement, which is beta3. It produced no message to indicate what happened. Looks like we'll need to remove that requirement from composer.json and rely on Drupal itself enforcing it.

Answer (score 1):

This is something I haven't seen before.

Look at the output you shared:
"Installing drupal/commerce (2.0.0-beta3)"
The current version is RC1, beta3 is from last November. That's why you're getting the message about missing modules.

What makes this problem even weirder is that you got the most recent version of project-base, as well as Address. You only received an ancient version of Commerce.

Try deleting the folder and rerunning the command. If that still gives you the same result, try "composer clear-cache" first, then the command.

Comment: I've tried it again with the clear-cache command, I even removed the apt-version of composer and downloaded the latest composer from https://getcomposer.org/install, but I keep getting the same version (Installing drupal/commerce (2.0.0-beta3): Downloading (100%)).

Comment: Do you think this has something to do with me being on debian stable and having some older packages from apt, or is this some other bug in the whole composer process?

Comment: System packages don't affect Composer. It sounds like a hiccup on the Composer side (a stale cache somewhere, perhaps).

Comment: I just tried the command locally and it completed fine, giving me RC1. Can you try appending "--verbose" to the command, so that we can get more output? Might help spot the issue.

Comment: Additionally a `composer why drupal/commerce` might give some insight as to why its downloading an older version of commerce.

Comment: Also, please tell us which version of composer you are using, it may be a composer bug in handling the order of packages in the metadata and choosing the wrong one.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I was reading a bit more on getcomposer.org and I just figured the whole issue is probably the composer.json file that I missed out on. The 'composer why drupal/commerce' kindly pointed it out as confirmation.
I'll try and figure out where I can get that file and I'll get back to confirm or deny that that's the issue. Cheers.

Comment: OK, I'm about to give up on this :( The documentation is so confusing and spread out so I'm just going to ask... where can I get a composer.json so I can get this site up and running? `composer why drupal/commerce` gives me an error _Could not find package "drupal/commerce" in your project_.

Comment: composer create-project clones the project from github.com/drupalcommerce/project-base, which has the composer.json. Then it runs composer install. Anyway, we're still missing the "--verbose" output.

Comment: Sorry Bojan, I updated the original post with the verbose output. It says patch available but patching is disabled. I am sure I didn't disable anything like that out of my free will, I like things to be up to date.